# Passing a struct to a function gives TypeError: Internal or recursive type not allowed

Tags: solidity, contract-development, arrays, struct

I am trying to pass in a `struct` to the constructor of a contract but am getting the error

```
TypeError: Internal or recursive type is not allowed for public or external functions
```

The contract is

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Writer {

  struct Paragraph {
    string[] lines;
  }

  struct Essay {
    Paragraph[] paragraphs;
  }

  Essay[] private essays;

  function Writer(Essay initialEssay) {
    essays.push(initialEssay);
  }

}
```

I did some digging and it seems the issue is not actually to do with the `struct` being defined within the contract (where else would it be defined after all) but with the nested array, so I changed it to

```
contract Writer {

  struct Paragraph {
    string sentances;
  }

  struct Essay {
    string title;
    Paragraph[] paragraphs;
  }

  Essay[] private essays;

  function Writer(Essay essay) {
    essays.push(essay);
  }

}
```

but now I get

```
InternalCompilerError: Static memory load of more than 32 bytes requested.
```

So then I tried this way, manually constructing the `struct`.

```
contract Writer {

  struct Paragraph {
    string sentances;
  }

  struct Essay {
    string title;
    Paragraph[] paragraphs;
  }

  Essay[] private essays;

  function Writer(string title, string[] _paras) {
    Paragraph[] storage paras;
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < _paras.length; i++) {
        Paragraph memory para = Paragraph(_paras[i]);
        paras.push(para);
    }
    Essay memory initialEssay = Essay(title, paras);
    essays.push(initialEssay);
  }
}
```

which gives

```
UnimplementedFeatureError: Nested arrays not yet implemented.
```

Should I perhaps ditch using a `struct` and instead define a new contract to represent an `Essay`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass a nested array as a function parameter if that function is external. When you are trying to pass _paras it will fail because string[] is a nested array.

The simplest solution for your problem, if it is not a lot of parameters is to just pass them each one as a separate parameter, construct the struct inside the function and push it to the array.

It would be like the last implementation you tried but instead pos passing string[] params you would pass string param1, string param2, string param3, etc.

Comment: Okay thanks. That’s kind of what I was afraid of. Alas the incoming data structure (as currently being proposed) is quite complex. Back to the drawing board with that one I think.

Comment: Is this still valid? It's not possible to pass, e.g. a string[] as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create a reference first then assign values

```
uint256 idx = essays.length;
essays.push();
Essay storage e= essays[idx];
e.paragraphs.push(Paragraph("your sentense");
```