# Unable to declare public mapping in Solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development, mapping

When I try compiling the following on Remix:

```
contract Betting{
    struct Player{
        mapping(uint => uint) amounts;

    }

    struct Match{
        address [] playerAdresses;
        uint [] totalBets;
    }

    mapping(address => Player) public playerInfo;
    mapping(uint => Match) public matchInfo;
}
```

I get the error `TypeError: Internal or recursive type is not allowed for public state` for both `playerInfo` and `matchInfo`. However when I remove both `uint [] totalBets` and `mapping(uint => uint) amounts` these errors go away. Exactly why does that happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here seems to be with the getters that are created when you declare the variables public, changing the visibility to internal cancels the error. [In this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29217/passing-a-struct-to-a-function-gives-typeerror-internal-or-recursive-type-not-a?rq=1) it is explained that passing nested arrays is the problem.

Note that in both cases adding a fix-length variable to the structs cancels the errors.

Furthermore, the first mapping can be done using:

`mapping(address => mapping(uint => uint)) public playerInfo;`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Fixed-length arrays do not compile either fyi: `struct MS { uint[2] blah }; mapping(uint=>MS) public myMap;` doesn't work